# Replacing NA values using a rolling window

Tags: r

How can I replace a NA value by the average of the previous non-NA and next non-NA values?
For example, I want to replace the first NA value by -0.873, and the 4th/5th by the average of -0.497+53.200.

Thanks!

```
t <- c(NA, -0.873, -0.497, NA, NA, 53.200, NA, NA, NA, 26.100)
```

=================== ADD ON ===================
Thank you all for answering the question! Sorry for the late response. This is only a part of a dataframe (10000 * 91) and I only took out the first 10 rows from the first column in order to simplify the question. I think David and MKR have the result that I am expected to have.

Comment: `t[1] <- -0.873; t[4] <- t[5] <- mean(t[3:6], na.rm = T)`?

Comment: Well thought question. Perhaps there is a need for new form of `rollapply`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible vectorized approach using base R (some steps could be probably improved but I have no time to look into it right now)

```
x <- c(NA, -0.873, -0.497, NA, NA, 53.200, NA, NA, NA, 26.100)

# Store a boolean vector of NA locaiotns for firther use
na_vals <- is.na(x)

# Find the NAs location compaed to the non-NAs
start_ind <- findInterval(which(na_vals), which(!na_vals))

# Createa right limit
end_ind <- start_ind + 1L

# Replace zero locations with NAs
start_ind[start_ind == 0L] <- NA_integer_

# Calculate the means and replace the NAs
x[na_vals] <- rowMeans(cbind(x[!na_vals][start_ind], x[!na_vals][end_ind]), na.rm = TRUE)
x
# [1] -0.8730 -0.8730 -0.4970 26.3515 26.3515 53.2000 39.6500 39.6500 39.6500 26.1000
```

This should work properly for NAs on both sides of the vector.

Comment: clever, and also demonstrated that I may have misread the question... OP likely is looking for a window of size 3 (the one before and the one after)

Comment: Also pretty fast. Just tested it on 10M length vector - 0.8 secs.

Answer (score 2):

This function imputes values for `NA` in a vector based on the average of the non-`NA` values in a rolling window from the first element to the next element.

```
t <- c(NA, -0.873, -0.497, NA, NA, 53.200, NA, NA, NA, 26.100)

roll_impute <- function(x){
    n <- length(x)
    res <- x
    for (i in seq_along(x)){
        if (is.na(x[i])){
            res[i] <- mean(rep_len(x, i+1), na.rm = TRUE )
        }
    }
    if (is.na(x[n])) x[n] <- mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
    res
}
roll_impute(t)
# [1] -0.87300 -0.87300 -0.49700 -0.68500 17.27667 53.20000 17.27667 17.27667 19.48250
# [10] 26.10000
```

`roll_impute()` includes code that corrects the rolling window in the case that the final element is `NA`, so that the vector isn't recycled. This isn't the case in your example, but is needed in order to generalize the function. Any improvements on this function would be welcome :) It does use a for loop, but doesn't grow any vectors. No simple way to avoid the for loop and rely on the structure of the objects jumps to my mind right now.

Comment: But this changes all the other entries too, doesn't it? I.e. `t[2]`, `t[3]` etc. are all different. TBH, it's not very clear what OP wants, and there is very little information in the post.

Comment: Ugh. i completely did this wrong. Deleting and fixing

Comment: Now this does what I thought I was doing.

Comment: I agree with you in that's a systematic approach for replacing `NA`s. The only question is whether OP wants the last 3 `NA`s replaced as well. She/He only talks about `NA`s at positions `1, 4, 5`. There really should be an edit to the original question to clarify.

Comment: The title says the OP wants to do this for all the `NA` values, and then the body of the question uses the first two `NA` positions as examples. That part, at least, seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: Actually the title says "How to replace **a** NA value by the average of previous non-NA and next non-NA in R?" (bold is mine). But I don't want to split hairs. As I said, I think your approach is neat and systematic.

Comment: Why thank you :) I appreciate that coming from one of the top R tag contributors.

Answer (score 1):

One `dplyr` and `tidyr` based solution could be:

```
  library(dplyr)
  library(tidyr)
  t <- c(NA, -0.873, -0.497, NA, NA, 53.200, NA, NA, NA, 26.100)

  data.frame(t) %>%
    mutate(last_nonNA = ifelse(!is.na(t), t, NA)) %>%
    mutate(next_nonNA = ifelse(!is.na(t), t, NA)) %>%
    fill(last_nonNA) %>%
    fill(next_nonNA, .direction = "up") %>%
    mutate(t = case_when(
                        !is.na(t)  ~ t,
                        !is.na(last_nonNA) & !is.na(next_nonNA) ~ (last_nonNA + next_nonNA)/2,
                        is.na(last_nonNA) ~ next_nonNA,
                        is.na(next_nonNA) ~ last_nonNA
                        )
           ) %>%
    select(t)

  # t
  # 1  -0.8730
  # 2  -0.8730
  # 3  -0.4970
  # 4  26.3515
  # 5  26.3515
  # 6  53.2000
  # 7  39.6500
  # 8  39.6500
  # 9  39.6500
  # 10 26.1000
```

**Note:** It looks a bit complicated but it does the trick. One can achieve same thing via for loop.

Comment: This seems very overwrought to me. You're taking a structure, putting it into a data frame, using dplyr data frame wrappers around code that works, then taking the structure out of the data frame.

Comment: @DanHall I know. It's definitely is. That's what I had mentioned as part of note. But it does the trick and provides answer. Logic is pretty clear to understand. I'm sure OP is not using a simple vector either. He must be looking for a solution for a real world scenario involving more complicated data. Hence, thought to provide this idea.

Comment: You'd be surprised :) Often I run into files and problems that are best solved at the level of a vector. And a solution for a vector is a generalized solution. It can be applied to any higher level data structure, so long as you understand how that data structure is put together.

Comment: @DanHall Exactly that's what my point was. People start looking for solution in simple way and then build up on that to find efficient way.